# Stringify-ing a JavaScript array to send to PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, json, stringify

I have a multidimensional array in JavaScript and I need to send it to a PHP script.

Below is what I am doing to send the data at present but it's sending blank data.

I've narrowed it down to what I'm logging in the image.

Is there another way to send this or why is JSON.stringify appearing blank?

```
console.log(results);
console.log(JSON.stringify(results));

var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append("results", JSON.stringify(results));

fetch('myfile.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: form_data
})
```

[image]

### Edit

```
var response_object = {"1": response1, "2": response2};
var test_object = {[current_test]: response_object};
var section_object = {[current_section]: test_object};
results = { ...results, ...section_object }
```

Comment: Can you outline what the "Edit" was here? It is not clear what purpose it serves. Clarifying this may be helpful to future readers who would like to learn from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because you are not adding elements to array but only attaching properties  to it, like `'section1'` and `'test1'`, you should instead declare those properties on some objects then insert those object into array, see in the example below what happens and how you could avoid that:

```js
let result = [];

// BAD
result['section1'] = [];
result['section1']['test1'] = [, "2", "3"];
result['section1']['test2'] = [, "4", "5"];
result['section2'] = [];
result['section2']['test1'] = [, "2", "3"];
result['section2']['test2'] = [, "4", "5"];

console.log('BAD', JSON.stringify(result));

// GOOD
result = [{
  'section1': [
    {'test1': [, "2", "3"]},
    {'test2': [, "4", "5"]}
  ]
}, {
  'section2': [
    {'test1': [, "2", "3"]},
    {'test2': [, "4", "5"]}
  ]
}];

console.log('GOOD', JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: thanks for your response, this is what I had: `results["section"+current_section] = [];
results["section"+current_section]["test"+current_test] = [];
results["section"+current_section]["test"+current_test]["1"] = response1;
results["section"+current_section]["test"+current_test]["2"] = response2;` it is all written with variable names so rewriting it as 'new_result = [{
 "section"+current_section: [
  {"test"+current_test: ["asre", asre_response]},
  {"test"+current_test: ["spleeter", spleeter_response]}
 ]
}];
results.push(new_result);' gives me `Unexpected token '+'`

Comment: not quite so, dynamic object properties are set like this: {["test"+current_test]: [1, 2, 3] ..., i.e. you should add square brackets around dynamic property name

Comment: thanks for your help again I'm building this array dynamically so i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong each time i get two new responses i want to add them to the array but i'm overwriting them at the moment, see my edit above

Comment: according to your `console.log`, `results` is an array, so you should just add new items to it, i.e. `results.push(section_object)`

Comment: thanks for your help final working code is above

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted an answer on behalf of the question author, to move it to the answer space).*

Final working code:

```
var response_object = {"1": response1, "2": response2};
var test_object = {[current_test]: response_object};
if(results[current_section]){
    var section_object = { ...results[current_section], ...test_object};
    results[current_section] = section_object;
}else{
    var section_object = {[current_section]: test_object};
    results = { ...results, ...section_object};
}
```